# How to debug third party JavaScript libraries such as openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, web, debugging, django

I am able to work with web development tools like firebug and dev tools and solve bugs in my javascript files. But when it comes to bugs that produce errors such as "typeError: e is null" which prompts me to the third party js library I am using, how am I supposed to debug that issue?

I am creating a django app to integrate with a bigger django project. I am using openlayers as simple as possible and even though I am not getting any errors, apart from a css warning, my map division is not loading any maps...How am I supposed to work around this and of course any future similar problems?

Any advice or link would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you supply the OpenLayers code you used to initialize the map? Also, I've been using [olwidget](https://github.com/yourcelf/olwidget) with some success. Might be worth looking at.

Comment: While your'e at it, check out [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and this [django-leaflet](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet) plugin. I haven't tried it out yet but I will soon. Leaflet is much easier to use and the docs are great

Comment: thanks for the hints and tips. I am using leaflet as well. its giving me some trouble as well. I can use both Open layers and leaflet on simple stand alone web pages but something is going wrong when integrating into a big django project.

Comment: I am using openlayers-2.12

Comment: So, does anyone have experience on having no error shown and still having no map loading?

Comment: I'm using geodjango, but within admin only. Is geodjango an option or are the maps written in JavaScript?

Comment: When I encountered no map and no error it was the properties of the map div that messed me up. It needed a width and a height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, debugging JavaScript code is not as easy as debugging your python code although firebug has made the problem much simpler already.

When it comes to js libraries like OpenLayers, first make sure you have the uncompressed version for development. When some error occurs, you can find the source file and the code line the defect originates in Firebug's console with a link to script provided. Find the code that causes the error and set break point where appropriate and repeat the process just as how you debug in other programming language.

Personally I find the [firebug official documentation(faq & wiki)](http://getfirebug.com/faq/) is quite useful, and especially this [javascript debugging](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) page.

Answer (score 3):

All javascript libraries come in source form, so it is only a matter of taking the time to dive into the code. OpenLayers is no different, only you are probably using the minified, compressed into a single huge file version which is hard to read for humans.

To help with debugging you should use the non-minified version of the libraries when developing and switch to minified and unified versions in production.

With non-minified, non-unified versions of huge libraries like OpenLayers you will find inspecting code and debugging much easier.

For example OpenLayers ships with both a minified/unified single js file  (recommended for production and usually available under the root and the *build* directory) and the unminified source code tree in the *lib* directory.

Most modern development environments offer the possibility to minify and concat javascript and css as part of the build process.